# Dictator Application built in Excel 2010, works on 2007 & 2010, but users on 2013/Office 365 are getting locking cells formatting

Tags: excel, vba, office365, excel-2013

Pretty much what the title says.
I've inherited a Dicatator App built in Excel 2010. Pretty decent piece of work. Users on 2013 and 365 are getting locking of cells/ protection of the sheet where they should not.

I've checked the following at runtime:
- Application.Screenupdating = True
- Application.Calculation = xlAutoMatic
- There No events on Workbook Activate
- There no worksheet change events that are causing the error.

When a new workbook is created in the same Excel instance and I swop back to Dictator.
Hey presto its back to normal and accepting keystrokes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Any Application event class modules?

Comment: mmm...yes. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, Application event modules can also contain workbook/worksheet activate event code. Have you checked for those?